# keyword mysql search returning inaccurate results

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword

I am using the code below to search my database based on keywords given by the user. It seems to work fine for the most part, but i am searching both based on location and keywords. This is where I have the issues.

If i put no location in and search it returns all results regardless of location, which is fine. If i put in a location that does not exist and some keywords, It returns all results matching the keywords and seems to ignore the location.

Also if i leave the keywords empty and search by a location that does exist, it seem that it ignores the location again and just returns all results.

So it would seem my logic for setting the location is not working.

```
$keys = explode(" ",$tag);

    $search_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT providers.* FROM providers JOIN provider_tags ON providers.id = provider_tags.provider_Id JOIN tags ON provider_tags.tag_id = tags.id WHERE tags.tag_name LIKE '%$tag%' OR providers.provider_name LIKE '%$tag%' OR providers.provider_contact_name LIKE '%$tag%' OR providers.provider_features LIKE '%$tag%' ";

    foreach($keys as $k){
        $search_sql .= " OR tags.tag_name LIKE '%$k%' OR providers.provider_name LIKE '%$k%' OR providers.provider_contact_name LIKE '%$k%' OR providers.provider_features LIKE '%$k%' ";
    }

    $search_sql .= " AND (providers.provider_town LIKE '%{$location}%' OR providers.provider_local_area LIKE '%{$location}%' OR providers.provider_postcode LIKE '%{$location}%')";

    echo $search_sql;
    $gettags = mysqli_query($con, $search_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: As a tangent to this question, I would highly recommend that you look into natural language searches, as this is likely a much better solution to what you are doing.  Read about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a bunch of `OR` conditions in a loop and then a big `AND` condition for the location.  Your `AND` condition is checked with the last `OR` of the loop. If any of the others `OR` in the condition is `true` then you get a result no matters the `AND` condition.

**Edit :**

You'll probably get the results you want if you :

- wrap every `OR` conditions with parenthesis;
- wrap **all** the `OR` conditions together.

Something like :

```
$search_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT providers.* FROM providers JOIN provider_tags ON providers.id = provider_tags.provider_Id JOIN tags ON provider_tags.tag_id = tags.id WHERE ( (tags.tag_name LIKE '%$tag%' OR providers.provider_name LIKE '%$tag%' OR providers.provider_contact_name LIKE '%$tag%' OR providers.provider_features LIKE '%$tag%') ";

foreach($keys as $k){
    $search_sql .= " OR (tags.tag_name LIKE '%$k%' OR providers.provider_name LIKE '%$k%' OR providers.provider_contact_name LIKE '%$k%' OR providers.provider_features LIKE '%$k%') ";
}

$search_sql .= ") AND (providers.provider_town LIKE '%{$location}%' OR providers.provider_local_area LIKE '%{$location}%' OR providers.provider_postcode LIKE '%{$location}%')";
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to use parenthesis to group conditional together like this even if the operator precedence would give you the desired result without.  It just makes your intent much clearer.

Comment: thanks very much. I wrapped the entire length of OR statements in parenthesis and it sorted my issue. Many thanks